# Kibana 4:How to fetch and display MySQL data in Kibana dashboard?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, kibana-4

Using Kibana-4 how to display MySQL data on Kibana dashboard.

I was able to connect with database using curl operations:
XGET/XPUT

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?pretty&q=*'
```

shows the database details...

I followed---https://github.com/msimons/elasticsearch-river-jdbc

I create a new index after creating a sample `_river` elasticsearch pattern.

When I take the `_river` pattern in Kibana, I did not get the database data for creating the visualizations..

Any good video or url support for this problem ?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try restarting your elasticsearch and kibana instance?

Comment: thanks yuv,

few doubts,
i created an elastic search index say _river and i PUT some data through curl commands(mysql data...).
then i add new 'index pattern' named _river from kibana 'localhost:5601'.
but i couldn't see the data fetched from mysql db when i try create new visualization.

i'am getting the data connection response when i    
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?pretty&q=*'

Comment: I am not able to understand your point. As per the link mentioned :-
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",

So in This _river is not  your index. Your index name is jdbc.
_river denotes you are using a river & my_jdbc_river is the name of the river.

If you want to see that data in Kibana, Add Index by name of jdbc in Kibana.